# Syntax error from JSON.parse()

Tags: jquery, json

My custom method to get json from string:

```
function GetJSON(a) {
        if (typeof a !== "string" || !a || a == null) return null;
        a = a.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n|\t/g, '').replace(/\\/g, '/');
        return new Function("return " + a)();
    }

    var notes ='{editable:true,useAjax:false,notes:[{"top":76,"left":411,"width":30,"height":30,"text":"hill","editable":true},{"top":183,"left":556,"width":30,"height":30,"text":"lake","editable":true}]}';

    return GetJSON(notes); //<-- works fine

    //I am trying to replace my custom method with
      return JSON.parse(notes);
```

But I get syntax error when I call JSON.parse()

What can be wrong?

EDIT:
I pasted the actual value that I pass to JSON.parse() from debug output.

Comment: For future reference ("what can be wrong" when you receive a syntax error), syntax error means that your input is syntactically invalid, I.E. it is not following the grammar rules of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
notes = "{editable:true,useAjax:false,notes:[" + notes + "]}";
```

You forgot to quote your keys here.  It should be:

```
notes = '{"editable":true,"useAjax":false,"notes":[' + notes + ']}';
```

The final JSON should be:

```
var notes ='{"editable":true,"useAjax":false,"notes":[{"top":76,"left":411,...'
```

Comment: This was the issue!! Silly me.

Comment: Yeah, JSON.parse is really strict about syntax :-P

Answer (score 2):

Your notes portion is missing a `,` between the two `{}` sets, making it invalid JSON.

It should be

```
[..snip..] "editable":true}, ' + '{"top":20,"left"[...snip...]
                           ^^--- missing
```

Comment: There seems to be a comma in the code in the question (maybe it was edited?).